# link .a and .o files in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, mingw

I have two precompiled library: `X.a` and `Y.a` and a test.cpp (without main function) source code use these two libraries.

I compiled the C++ using:

`g++ -c test.cpp`

and I got 'test.o'.

Now how can I link these three together to generate a `.a` file because test.cpp use some function in X.a and Y.a and other GCC libraries?

BTW, I am doing these under Windows using MinGW. Can I rename this .a file to .lib and use this .lib in VC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now how can I link these three
>   together to generate a .a file because
>   test.cpp use some function in X.a and
>   Y.a and other GCC libraries?

`.a` is nothing more then `ar` archive containg all object files (`.o` files)

> Can I rename this .a file to .lib and
>   use this .lib in VC?

Yes, but it requires little trick to work. See: 
http://opensees.berkeley.edu/community/viewtopic.php?t=2267

Answer (score 3):

In order to add your object file to the static library you have to use the following command:

```
ar rcs X.a test.o
```

But if you are provided with X.a and Y.a I suppose you are not the author of X and Y, therefore I'm not sure you really want to join them!

You may decide to link every object file into a single executable instead, but you need the `main` function for it!

**EDIT:**
Also I suggest you to read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I need to use GCC to get a static library and use VC to link this static library as I have done some fortran stuff in GCC..

Comment: @David: unfortunately I don't know anything about VC, but it seems that vartec gave you some useful info.